# $\lim_{s \to 1^+} 1/\zeta(s) = 0$ obvious or not?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, mobius-function

I read the statement that

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \textrm{ for } \Re(s) > 1 \qquad (*)$$

In fact I can guess what the proof is: just expand both $\zeta$ and the right hand side of (*) as an Euler product, use $\Re(s) > 1$ to handwave away any concerns of changing the order of taking limits and taking products and conclude that the outcome of multiplying the right hand side of (*) by $\zeta(s)$ is the product of infinitely many $1$'s, hence 1 itself. So far so good.

Now suppose I wanted to evaluate the the limit $s \to 1^+$ of the right hand side of ( * ) , or in layman's terms, compute the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$. From (*) I would quickly conclude that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n} = 0 \qquad (**)$$

since $\zeta(1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}  = \infty$ (by the standard 'powers of 1/2'-argument) and, as we all know, $1/\infty = 0$. Very nice, very elementary, or... so it seems.

However the statement (**) is far from elementary: it is equivalent to the prime number theorem! (If you find that equivalence surprising: so did I. I [asked a question about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2981762/101420) three years ago, but the current question is about a different type of surprise that arises if we take this equivalence as given.)

We all know that the PNT is hard to prove. So what is wrong with simply taking the the limit $s \to 1$ in (*) as I did above? Am I secretly interchanging two limits where that is not allowed?

**Where am I oversimplifying things?**

I have a very vague feeling what is going on here (but perhaps I am completely off, so correct me if I am wrong) and that is that there is some weird theorem lurking in the background that states that we can only extend the equation (*) to the *point* $s = 1$ if and only if we can extend it to the entire *line* $\{s \colon \Re(s) = 1\}$. But what kind of weird theorem would that be? It goes again my nearly lifelong experience that one can do mathematics just fine without even realizing that complex numbers off the real line exist.

Comment: You are claiming that $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1^+}\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\lim_{s \rightarrow 1^+}\,\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}}$. This is interchanging limits, is it not?

Comment: Hm, yes, but why is it forbidden? O wait, I can see it, the sum on the right hand side converges, but it does not converge absolutely because replacing the $\mu$'s with $|\mu|$'s would make the sum run off to infinity. Hmmmm.... Maybe it is that simple?

Comment: That’s precisely it. It takes careful justification to interchange limits, any limits (including convergent – or even absolutely convergent – sums).

Comment: $$\lim_{s\to1^+}\sum_{n}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\lim_{s\to1^+}\prod_p\left(1-\frac1{p^s}\right)$$ Thaking the log of right side: $$\lim_{s\to1^+}\sum_p\log\left(1-\frac1{p^s}\right)$$ and $\log(1-x)<-x$ for $x>0.$ So $$\leq-\lim_{s\to 1^+}\sum_{p}\frac1{p^s}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Wait, the limit you end up with is $-\infty$, right? So if the log of the quantity I am trying to compute is $\leq -\infty$ doesn't that imply that the quantity itself is 0 after all? But then you suddenly have a very simple elementary proof of PNT. I guess what I am trying to ask is: what are you trying to say?

Comment: No, I was thinking of that too – but Thomas Andrews is just computing $1/\zeta(s)$ as $s$ goes to $1$.

Comment: O, right! That is a nice way to put it

Comment: Yes, my argument also gives zero.

Comment: the fact that $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1^+}\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}}=0$ is trivial given the usual manipulations that show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}}=1/\zeta(s), \Re s >1$; the hard part is to show that one can interchange limits and series as that is not true in general (for example for any $t \ne 0$, one has $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(\sigma+it) \to \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(1+it), \sigma \to 1^+$ but the corresponding Dirichlet series oscillates with bounded partial sums

Comment: I think the result should be fairly easy to prove with elementary methods. I'm trying a proof now.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think I proved it elementarily. The hardest thing was drawing the Zeta symbol. But the fact that no one else spotted this elementary proof makes me doubt my attempt. I'll post it anyway and see what happens...

Comment: @AdamRubinson As far as I know the elementary proof of the PNT by Erdős and Selberg is considered quite technical.

Comment: No, I mean an elementary proof of the question in the title: that "$\lim_{s \to 1^+} 1/\zeta(s) = 0$ is obvious or not?" Or is this not what the OP wants answering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments to the other answer, the question in the title (which the other answer addresses) does not match the actual question I was asking in the body of my post. However *that* question has been answered in the comments to the original post; I am just writing this community wiki answer stating that the question has been answered in the comments to be able to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

The question in the title is:

> $\lim_{s \to 1^+} 1/\zeta(s) = 0$ obvious or not?

From the body of the text, I'm not sure that this is the real question the poster intended, but I answer the above question as it stands.

**Claim**: Suppose $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers with $a_n\to 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = +\infty.$ Then, $\lim_{s\to 1^+} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^s = \infty.$

**Proof**: Let $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ (think about $\gamma$ being a large positive real number). We are given that $\sum a_n$ diverges to $+\infty.$ So, $\exists k$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{k} a_n > 2\gamma$.

Proposition: $\exists s>1$ such that ${a_n}^s > a_n/2\quad \forall n\in \{1,\ldots,k\}.$ Proof of proposition: Take $s = 1+a_k.$

Therefore, $\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}^s > \sum_{n=1}^{k}{a_n}^s > \sum_{n=1}^{k}{\frac{a_n}{2}} > \gamma.$

Furthermore, $1 <s' < s \implies \sum {a_n}^{s'} > \sum{a_n}^s,\ $ and so $\lim_{s\to 1^+} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^s = \infty.$

This proves that claim. Now take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}.$ We see that the question in the title is proven.

Comment: The series in OP's question is not a positive series.

Comment: @SangchulLee I thought $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1^s} + \frac{1}{2^s} + \frac{1}{3^3} + \ldots$

Comment: I assume Adam is applying the claim of this answer to $\zeta(s)$, not $1/\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Yeah but in what universe is $\lim_{s\to 1^+} \frac{1}{f(s)} = 0$ not that same as: $\lim_{s\to 1^+} f(s) = +\infty$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it was a question about obtaining $(**)$ from $(*)$, as it was the main topic in the comments. Indeed, showing $\zeta(s)\to\infty$ as $s\to1^+$ should be no hard, for instance using the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Right, I see now. I agree that showing $\lim_{s \to 1^+} 1/\zeta(s)= 0$ is obvious. My real question was if the obviousness of this fact, together with the truth of ( * ) makes ( * * ) equally obvious or not, but you are right that the title of the question does therefor not match the actual question.