# Riemann Hypothesis implies Prime number theorem?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, riemann-hypothesis

Following this thread [Prime number theorem and Möbius μ
function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2981762/prime-number-theorem-and-m%C3%B6bius-mu-function)

I was looking into Apostol's book, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, Springer 2000. And also note that RH is equivalent to Mertens conjecture, I thought if one can prove PNT using RH (Given the hypothesis is true)

Comment: What do you mean ? A known theorem can be the consequence of the truth of an unsolved conjecture. What is your question ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the prime number theorem is equivalent to the fact that the nontrivial zeros of the zeta function lie in the interior of the critical strip, i.e., they satisfy $0<\text{Im}(z)<1$. The Riemann hypothesis says they satisfy $\text{Im}(z)=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Consequences

Some simple thoughts:
The simplest and obvious connection i could think between something similar to Riemann zeta function and prime number estimates is:
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{n} = \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \times \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \times \sum_p \frac{1}{p^3} \times ..... $$

$$\sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \times \sum_p \frac{1}{p^3} \times ..... \leq \left(\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2$$

Hence:

$$\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$$ diverges. Hence asymptotically $n^{th}$ prime number $p_n$ is such that for every $\epsilon>0$ the following happens infinitely often, $$n < p_n < n^{1+\epsilon}$$

Of course there are clearly better estimates of $n^{th}$ prime number than this. But i see this as the easiest connection.